# Чи правильно "рушник" називати "полотенцем"?

Tags: значення-слів, різниця-між-словами, синоніми

Коли я був дитиною, то не раз чув як моя бабуся називала рушник "полотенцем". Нещодавно вирішив подивитися чи є таке слово в СУМі. Воно там справді є, але його значення зовсім не відповідаються значенню "рушник":

> 1. Те саме, що полотно 1. [Маруся (перебиває):] Ось годі, мамо, а то ви будете тут плакатись, а в городі чиїсь свині вбілять ваше полотенце
>      (Степан Васильченко, III, 1960, 82); — Попрядуть люди, погнити не
>      дадуть [прядиву]. Та й викине [Ошіська] на весну полотенця шматків
>      чималенько (Андрій Головко, II, 1957, 24).
> 2. Частина мережки, яка являє собою широку смугу ажурного візерунка та розділяє групи дірочок у ньому. Рапорт у третьому ряді складається, як
>      і в першому, з двох полотенець та двох стовпчиків (Українське народне
>      художнє вишивання, 1958, 20).
> 3. Перетинка на лапці водоплавного птаха.
> 4. спец. Зменш.-пестл. до полотно

[Рушник](http://sum.in.ua/s/rushnyk):

> 1. Довгастий шматок тканини (бавовняної, лляної, полотняної і т. ін.) для витирання обличчя, тіла, посуду тощо. Прокоповичка обстелила край
>      стола рушниками, щоб утирати губи й руки (Нечуй-Левицький, III, 1956,
>      71); Маруся дістала з комода рушник, повісила на цвях біля умивальника
>      (Андрій Головко, II, 1957, 442). ▲ Сталевий (стальний) рушник — довгий
>      лист сталі для піднімання затонулих суден. Під корпусом затонулого
>      судна в ґрунті морського дна водолази прорили 12 тунелів і протягли
>      крізь кожний з них міцний стальний рушник (Яків Перельман, Цікава
>      фізика.., 1950, 134).
> 2. Шматок декоративної тканини з вишиваним або тканим орнаментом; традиційно використовується для оздоблення житла, в українських
>      народних обрядах і т. ін. Стіни Галя вбрала шпалерами, пообвішувала
>      вишиваними рушниками (Панас Мирний, I, 1949, 359); — По конях і на
>      Семипілки! Весільних рушників не знімати, молода іде з нами (Олександр
>      Довженко, I, 1958, 158);  * Образно. На хмарних рушниках зоря квітки
>      виводить... (Володимир Сосюра, I, 1957, 56);  * У порівняннях. В
>      Румунії зустріли нас, Як рідних, бідаки. У них вузенькі ниви, Неначе
>      рушники (Микола Нагнибіда, Вибр., 1950, 201).

Спробував пошукати чи не є ці два слова синонімами, але, на жаль, не отримав ніякого результату.

І все ж, я знайшов приклади вживання слова "полотенце" у значенні "шматок тканини (бавовняної, лляної, полотняної і т. ін.) для витирання обличчя, тіла, посуду тощо":

*Обов'язково учасникам зборів з собою взяти полотенце (для душу) та полотенце (пляжне для басейну).* - [сайт карате-клубу Tay-Sen](http://tay-sen.com.ua/news.php?id=343&m_lang_id=8).

*Я вирішила взяти полотенце,і піти шукати ванну кімнату* - я так зрозумів, що це якась історія на сайті [Wattpad](https://www.wattpad.com/454874844-%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5-sms).

Звичайно зрозуміло, що джерела не є офіційними і довіряти їм не можна. Але я переконався, що в таком значенні люди справді вживають це слово. Але чи правильно це?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Слово "полетенце" дійсно вживають в значенні "шматок тканини (бавовняної, лляної, полотняної і т. ін.) для витирання обличчя, тіла, посуду тощо". Особисто я та мої рідні "полетенцем" інколи називаємо "рушник". Думала, що це суржик і все. Якби не Ваше питання навіть не думала шукати, визначення в СУМ для слова  "полетенце".

"Полетенце" суржик з російської мови

[Російсько-український академічний словник 1924–33рр. (А. Кримський, С. Єфремов)](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on)

> Полоте́нце – рушни́к.

[Словник-антисуржик](http://slovopedia.org.ua/45/53407/300232.html)

> ПОЛОТЕНЦЕ  рушник

На мою думку, краще обмежити вживання слова "полотенце" в значені "шматок тканини (бавовняної, лляної, полотняної і т. ін.) для витирання обличчя, тіла, посуду тощо" та надати перевагу слову "рушник". Тим паче, в інших словниках  не знайшла слово "полотенце" з таким же значення як "рушник"